# PHP: explode array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

i have two `table` for `article` and `setting`. in article `table` i put `id,title,date ..etc` and in settings `table`, i have row with name `featuredarticle` and put `id` of article with separate comma for featured articles. now i need to list/print my featured article only. how to ?

TABLE articles:

```
ID | TITLE | DATE | PUBLISH
1
2
3
4
5
```

TABLE settings / row featuredarticle:

```
1,2,5
```

[image]

Comment: You will need to add some additional detail here. How far do you get? Do you have a working MySQL query? Are you getting any error messages? etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    articles a
        INNER JOIN settings b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(a.ID, b.featuredarticle) <> 0
```

- [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

If you have time to change the table schema, change it. It is a bad design to have columns vith value separated by a comma.

Comment: i see this error : `Error 1054: Unknown column 'b.featuredarticle' in 'on clause'`. i now this bad design, but i custom the any modules of cms And I have no choice.

Comment: @BaTmaN how come you have an unknown column? can you post the result of this query please, `DESC articles` and `DESC settings`

Comment: sorry but, i dont care how to work `DESC articles` and `DESC settings` query! can u tell me how to work this?

Answer (score 0):

Get data from DB to array and use:

$newArray = explode(".", $dataDbArray);

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
SELECT * FROM article
     JOIN settings ON FIND_IN_SET( id, featuredarticle)
```

Please have a look at demo: [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21466/3)

Comment: LEFT JOIN is not needed here, the OP states `i need to list/print my featured article only`

Comment: @SureshKamrushi : i see this error: `Error 1054: Unknown column 'featuredarticle' in 'on clause'`. i add screen of options table. please see this.